# Error with Jquery Ajax Success Event and Receiving Response Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax-request

I am calling jQuery Ajax function, everything works fine.. except, it is not receving any response and appending it in.

When form is submitted.. beforeSend event is called and loading image successfully runs, and also there is an alert box with message 'Deleted', but the request and response from page is not appended.... in network tab of chrome, i can see message of selected post deleted... but its not appending in page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#post").submit(function() {
        var post = $('#post').val();
        var token = $('#token').val();
        var str = 'token='+ token + '&post='+ post;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "http://localhost/delete.php",
            data: str,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#post").html('<img src="http://localhost/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Deleting...');
           },
            success: function(msg) {
                alert('Deleted');
                $("#post").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                    $("#post").html(msg);
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You can remove the '$('#post').ajaxComplete()' and use only '$('#post').html(msg);'

Comment: is that the only solution ? but someone said me to use ajaxComplete function ?

Comment: Try this, the ajaxComplete and success function is redundant. The ajaxComplete is for use out of $.ajax, this trigger all ajax function success

Answer (score 1):

You're attaching a **new event listener** to `#post` after the AJAX query succeeds. Basically what you're saying is, "after this query succeeds, wait for another query to succeed and then change the HTML." Since the query has already succeeded, you need to remove `ajaxComplete` and simply use:

```
success: function() {
    alert('Deleted');
    $("#post").html(msg);
}
```